# using draggable.helper but i wanted to add helper to the dom, and it doesnt like it

Tags: javascript, jquery

The sample i been working with is located here:  http://jsfiddle.net/aLnJG/3/

Essentially i have draggable giving a helper, which is an inputbox...  and then on drop, i wanted to append the helper to the canvas.

Code:

```
$("div#controlList > div").draggable({
    helper: function(){ return $("<input type='text' />");}
});

$("div#canvas").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui){
        $("<li />").append($(ui.helper[0])).appendTo(this);
    }
});
```

It seems that when i inspect the element, a DIV is added to #CANVAS, but has no contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
 ui.helper.clone().css({position:"",top:"", left:""});
```

when dealing with draggable, they are going to be draggable, so that removed them.  There might be a way to remove draggable from this particular object, but it wasnt working with:

```
 u.helper.clone().draggable("destroy")
```